# Minimal coupling in Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, dirac-equation, gauge-invariance

In the framework of relativistic quantum mechanics (not QFT) the Dirac equation in presence of external electromagnetic field is obtained by means of the minimal coupling, i.e. the substitution:

$$p_{\mu} \rightarrow p_{\mu}-eA_{\mu}$$

This substitution is often motivated by saying that it "ensures gauge invariance of the theory" (Greiner "Relativistic quantum mechanics", page 121). The resuting "modified" Dirac equation is:

$$i\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=\left( \vec{\alpha} \left( \vec{p}-e\vec{A} \right)+\beta m + e \phi\right)\psi$$
This equation seems to change if one changes the 4-potential by a gauge transformation $A_{\mu}\rightarrow A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\Lambda$. So what does it mean that the minimal coupling ensures gauge invariance? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the phase transformation of $\psi$.

The Dirac equation is indeed not invariant to the
gauge transformation
$$A_{\mu}\rightarrow A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\Lambda$$
alone.

But it is invariant to the combined gauge/phase transformation
$$\begin{align}
A_{\mu}&\rightarrow A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\Lambda \\
\psi &\rightarrow \exp\left(-\frac{ie\Lambda}{\hbar}\right)\psi
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing?

You are missing the fact that a gauge transformation transforms $\psi$ as well. It changes the complex phase of the spinor at each point in spacetime. See if you can figure out how much of a phase change will leave the equation unchanged.

It’s this local phase change of the matter field that explains why the gauge group for electromagnetism is called $U(1)$.